# How to add an external javascript page in a .php page?

Tags: javascript, php, netbeans

So my .php file was previously a .html page, however i wanted to add a session within this file and use javascript to validate my forms. But when i add the  in the  tag, nothing happens. It was working fine when my file was .html... Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php
session_start();
?>

 <html>
      <html>
      <head> 
          <title>Hompage</title> 
         <script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script> 
      </head> 

      <body style = "margin-left:5%;"> 
           <form method = "post" id = "Form1" action = "my_js.js">
           <b>Login:</b>
           <br/>
           <br/>
                 User Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                 <input type="text" name="uname" id ="uname"/> 
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
                 Password: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                 <input type="text" name="pwd" id ="pwd"/> 

                 <br/>
                 <br/>

                 <input type ="button" id="Login" value ="Login" onclick = "validate();"/>
           </form>  
           <br/><br/>
           <hr/>    
           <br/><br/>

           <form method = "post" name = "Form2" id = "Form2" action="register_add.php">
           <b>Register:</b>
           <br/>
           <br/>
                 <span style = "color: red;">*</span> First Name:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                 <input type="text" name="fname" id ="fname"/> 
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
                 <span style = "color: red;">*</span> Last Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                 <input type="text" name="lname" id ="lname"/>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
                 <span style = "color: red;">*</span> Date of Birth: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                 <input type = "text" name = "dob" id ="y" value = "yyyy/mm/dd">
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
                 <span style = "color: red;">*</span> User Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                 <input type="text" name="uname" id ="uname"/>
                 <br/>
                 <br/>
                 <span style = "color: red;">*</span> Password: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
                 <input type="password" name="pwd" id ="pwd"/>

                 <br/>
                 <br/>

                 <input type ="Submit" id="Register" value ="Register"/>
           </form>


      </body> 

</html>
```

And my .js file:

```
// Login Form Validation
function validate(){
      var x=document.forms["Form1"]["uname"].value; 
      var y=document.forms["Form1"]["pwd"].value;
      if (x==null || x=="" || uname == null){ 
      //alert("User name must be filled out"); 
        document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "User Name field must be filled out";
        return false; 
                }
      if (y==null || y=="" || pwd==null){
        document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "Password field must be filled out";
        return false;
                }
      else{
        document.getElementById('Form1').innerHTML="User Name: " + x + "\nPassword: " + y;
                    }

    // Registration Form Validation
    var a=document.forms["Form2"]["fname"].value;
    var b=document.forms["Form2"]["lname"].value;
    var c=document.forms["Form2"]["m"].value;
    var d=document.forms["Form2"]["d"].value;
    var e=document.forms["Form2"]["y"].value;
    var f=document.forms["Form2"]["uname"].value;
    var g=document.forms["Form2"]["pwd"].value;
    if (var==null || var==""){
         document.getElementById('para2').innerHTML = "All field with '*' must be filled out";
         return false;
            }
     else{
        document.getElementById('Form2').innerHTML="First Name: " + a + "\nLast Name: " + b +"\nDate of Birth: " + m + d + y + "\nUsername: " + uname + "\nPassword: " + pwd;
            }
    }
```

Comment: is the `my_js.js` file in the same directory as this php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your javascript had some errors.  Remember to use the dev tools (F12 in chrome/IE) and check the console.

The updated code and .js are below...what I did was:

- Remove all the var = as they were throwing errors on my end.
- Your error messages for login and register (id="para1" and div id="Para2") did not have the elements on the page so I added them.
- I finished up the registration test code  (some form elements where miss named and throwing errors...comments where added to the JS line 21).

What you will want to do is separate these methods (ValidateLogin() and ValidateRegistration()) or make them more generic by looping through the form variables checking for a required attribute possibly?

Working Code:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head> 
     <title>Hompage</title> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script> 
  </head> 
<?php
session_start();
?>
  <body style = "margin-left:5%;"> 

       <form method = "post" id = "Form1" action = "my_js.js">
       <b>Login:</b>
       <br/>
       <br/>
             User Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
             <input type="text" name="uname" id ="uname"/> 
             <br/>
             <br/>
             Password: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
             <input type="text" name="pwd" id ="pwd"/> 

            <div id="para1"></div>
             <br/>
             <br/>

             <input type ="button" id="Login" value ="Login" onclick = "validate();"/>
       </form>

       <br/>
       <br/>
       <hr/>   
       <br/>
       <br/>

       <form method = "post" name = "Form2" id = "Form2" action="register_add.php" >
       <b>Register:</b>
       <br/>
       <br/>
             <span style = "color: red;">*</span> First Name:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
             <input type="text" name="fname" id ="fname"/> 
             <br/>
             <br/>
             <span style = "color: red;">*</span> Last Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
             <input type="text" name="lname" id ="lname"/>
             <br/>
             <br/>
             <span style = "color: red;">*</span> Date of Birth: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
             <input type = "text" name = "dob" id ="y" value = "yyyy/mm/dd">
             <br/>
             <br/>
             <span style = "color: red;">*</span> User Name: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
             <input type="text" name="uname" id ="uname"/>
             <br/>
             <br/>
             <span style = "color: red;">*</span> Password: &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
             <input type="password" name="pwd" id ="pwd"/>

             <br/>
             <br/>
             <div id="para2"></div>
             <input type ="button" id="Register" value ="Register" onclick = "validate();"/>
       </form>


  </body> 

</html>
```

JS Script:

```
function validate() {
    x = document.forms["Form1"]["uname"].value;
    y = document.forms["Form1"]["pwd"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "" || uname == null) {
        //alert("User name must be filled out"); 
        document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "User Name field must be filled out";
        return false;
    }
    if (y == null || y == "" || pwd == null) {
        document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = "Password field must be filled out";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Form1').innerHTML = "User Name: " + x + "\nPassword: " + y;
    }

    // Registration Form Validation
    a = document.forms["Form2"]["fname"].value;
    b = document.forms["Form2"]["lname"].value;
    dob = document.forms["Form2"]["dob"].value;
    ///These values do not exist in the form...commenting them out 
    //c=document.forms["Form2"]["m"].value;
    //d=document.forms["Form2"]["d"].value;
    //e=document.forms["Form2"]["y"].value;
    f = document.forms["Form2"]["uname"].value;
    g = document.forms["Form2"]["pwd"].value;
    if ((a == null || a == "") || (b == null || b == "") || (dob == null || dob == "") || (f == null || f == "") || (g == null || g == "")) {
        document.getElementById('para2').innerHTML = "All field with '*' must be filled out";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('Form2').innerHTML = "First Name: " + a + "\nLast Name: " + b + "\nDate of Birth: " + m + d + y + "\nUsername: " + uname + "\nPassword: " + pwd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i totally forgot to remove those extra vars... It works now, how i want it to...

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

before the

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Thank you!! this helped with my session idea, and i am able to keep my user logged in so they can perform several actions on the site :)